# Hibernate Persist for large field values gives ConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

I am facing an issue with persisting records for an Entity(YieldCurveArchive) with  a field (reason) having a length equivalent to 2048 characters. Following are the scenarios and their results:

- Upload new Entity with smaller reason fields: Works fine.
- Upload Entity with reason fields
  changed with larger (2048 characters) data set: Works fine. Again as
  above. This is an update of the existing records.
- Upload new Entity
  with larger (2048 characters) reason fields: Fails.

I have also tried flushing the hibernate query buffer using entityManager.flush() but the above test results do not change.

I suspect there could be an issue with the buffering that Hibernate performs before actually doing a final insert into database:

- Selection of the available records in database to compare with
  existing dataset.
- Insert being fired but only kept in the buffer of
  hibernate to fire a bulk update.
- Another select being fired for a
  different client. Upon seeing another select, hibernate decides to
  fire the insert into the database and then fails.

An excerpt of the trace from the failed logs:

```
2013-07-02 12:46:00,792  WARN [pool-1-thread-4]: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
2013-07-02 12:46:00,792 ERROR [pool-1-thread-4]: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("CORE_TOTEM"."YC_MONTHLY_ARCHIVE"."PKEY")

2013-07-02 12:46:00,792  WARN [pool-1-thread-4]: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
2013-07-02 12:46:00,792 ERROR [pool-1-thread-4]: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("CORE_TOTEM"."YC_MONTHLY_ARCHIVE"."PKEY")

2013-07-02 12:46:00,985 ERROR [pool-1-thread-4]: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
                        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
                        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
                        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
                        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
                        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
                        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
                        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:64)
                        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:996)
                        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1141)
                        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
                        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:65)
                        at markit.totem.dao.DaoHelper.list(DaoHelper.java:19)
                        at com.markit.totem.rates.yieldcurve.dao.YieldCurveArchiveDao.getArchivesMonthly(YieldCurveArchiveDao.java:172)
                        at com.markit.totem.rates.yieldcurve.dao.YieldCurveArchiveDao$$FastClassByCGLIB$$55ef1569.invoke(<generated>)
                        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
                        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:628)
                        at com.markit.totem.rates.yieldcurve.dao.YieldCurveMonthlyArchiveDao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6aa04fe7.getArchivesMonthly(<generated>)
                        at com.markit.totem.rates.yieldcurve.results.upload.monthly.YieldCurveMonthlyArchivePersister.getExisting(YieldCurveMonthlyArchivePersister.java:38)
                        at com.markit.totem.rates.yieldcurve.results.upload.YieldCurveArchivePersister.persist(YieldCurveArchivePersister.java:68)
                        at com.markit.totem.rates.yieldcurve.results.upload.YieldCurveArchivePersister$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ac0db3fb.invoke(<generated>)
                        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
                        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:628)
                        at com.markit.totem.rates.yieldcurve.results.upload.monthly.YieldCurveMonthlyArchivePersister$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4b00cfa0.persist(<generated>)
                        at com.markit.totem.rates.yieldcurve.results.upload.YieldCurveResultsUploader.upload(YieldCurveResultsUploader.java:158)
                        at com.markit.totem.rates.yieldcurve.results.upload.YieldCurveResultsUploadTask.run(YieldCurveResultsUploadTask.java:53)
                        at com.markit.totem.workflow.WorkflowExecutor.executeWorkflowTask(WorkflowExecutor.java:258)
                        at com.markit.totem.workflow.WorkflowExecutor.executeSubWorkflow(WorkflowExecutor.java:227)
                        at com.markit.totem.workflow.WorkflowExecutor.access$000(WorkflowExecutor.java:17)
                        at com.markit.totem.workflow.WorkflowExecutor$1.run(WorkflowExecutor.java:72)
                        at markit.totem.dao.Transactionator.execute(Transactionator.java:19)
                        at markit.totem.dao.Transactionator$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c9204755.invoke(<generated>)
                        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
                        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:700)
                        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
                        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
                        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
                        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
                        at markit.totem.dao.Transactionator$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4eec78e2.execute(<generated>)
                        at com.markit.totem.workflow.WorkflowExecutor.execute(WorkflowExecutor.java:83)
                        at com.markit.totem.workflow.WorkflowExecutor.execute(WorkflowExecutor.java:213)
                        at com.markit.totem.workflow.WorkflowManager$OldWorkflow.execute(WorkflowManager.java:218)
                        at com.markit.totem.workflow.WorkflowManager$1.run(WorkflowManager.java:119)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("CORE_TOTEM"."YC_MONTHLY_ARCHIVE"."PKEY")

                        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:367)
                        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9055)
                        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
                        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
                        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
```

My initial thoughts were that it fails due to the encoding difference in database and default encoding from Hibernate.

Like underlying database uses Oracle and the NLS_CHARACTERSET is defined as:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
```

Hence it stores, 1 character as 4 bytes and any special character as 6 bytes. My insert into the Oracle fails for 1001 but passes till i insert 1000 characters. However, if I do an update with more characters thats not the case, which makes it more confusing.

Any pointers would be of great help?

Comment: You tried to insert NULL in column that don't accepts NULL (PKEY in YC_MONTHLY_ARCHIVE table)

Comment: You should know, that Oracle treat a empty string (length=0) like NULL.

Comment: Thats what the issue is, the column is not null. There are values in that field, only when the field values are greater than 1000 than this problem appears.